# Excel: Show a picture based on an expression

Tags: excel, ms-office, image

I have an excel spreadsheet. I have 3 different pictures, in cells A1, B1, C1.
Cell D1 has a value (one, two or three). Based on the value in D1, i need the cell E1 to display the picture in cell A1, A2 or A3

like this

```
if(d1="one"; display the picture in A1)
if(d1="two"; display the picture in B1)
if(d1="three"; display the picture in C
```

Any ideas how do I display the picture based on the IF function?

Comment: You cannot put pictures "in" a cell, only "over" it. All pictures "float" on the worksheet. You can position a picture over a cell by setting its Top and Left properties to the Top and Left of the cell.

Comment: is there any way i could actually use the left and top properties in a function?

Comment: What I was saying is you claim to have the pictures, in the cell, do you mean you have them Over the cells?

Comment: they're over the cell.
i've seen something like that a while ago in another excel document, it worked pretty much like an HTML iframe. Whatever was in the frame was being shown somewhere else. But I can't really find it now, and I never really managed to figure out how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Case Range("D1")
Case one
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3").Visible = False
Case two
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3").Visible = False
Case three
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3").Visible = True
End Select
```

Change the names of the picture to your picture names.